# What is the most popular replacement distro for OLPC?

Tags: linux, netbook, linux-distributions

I want to get rid of OLPC XO-1's builtin distribution (mostly because it's impossibly slow to use for anything, even browser and pdf reader).

What's the most popular replacement distro for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora, which is what the OLPC distribution is based on. You'll want [one of the prerelease versions](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/11.2.0) though, since the stable version is too large for comfort, not to mention old.

Answer (score 1):

[Puppy for the xo](http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=60155&sid=e01b6e7d2cd3ea3cec9354f000b00f8c)

My favorite linux on the olpc.